# Adding default field such as timestamp to json when rendering in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rendering

I am newbie in Ruby on rails and want to config render :json, always adds an extra field such as timestamp or version at the end of json response. Like this

```
    {
         //json data
         "time_stamp" : 24312512341235
    }
```

I think it might have better way to do that than adding parameter everytime calling render json
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like html, you can have a layout for JSON responses.

Create a file app/views/layouts/application.json.jbuilder
and fill it with this:

```
    json.merge! JSON.parse(yield)
    json.time_stamp Time.now.to_i
```

Note that you need to make sure you always return a JSON Object and not an Array.

Comment: Yep :D. Marked it down